# Raio de precisão - GoogleMaps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocalização

É possível identificar quando o raio de precisão está pequeno?

Nos exemplos abaixo quando abro o aplicativo ele está bem longe da minha localização, com um raio bem grande, no próximo o raio está bem pequeno e a localização está correta.

Primeiro imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segunda imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pra pegar localização estou usando:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
Location location;
GoogleApiClient mapGoogleApiClient;
FloatingActionButton myLoc, mt;
String latMt, logMt, t1, t2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    latMt = intent.getStringExtra("latmt");
    logMt = intent.getStringExtra("logmt");

    if (mapGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mapGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(MapsActivity.this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(MapsActivity.this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

 myLoc = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.locat);

  //Isto é tipo um setMyLocationEnabled

  myLoc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (GetLocalization(MapsActivity.this)) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    return;
                }
                location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mapGoogleApiClient);
                if (location != null) {
                    t1 = (String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
                    t2 = (String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));

                    LatLng target = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                    CameraPosition.Builder builder = new CameraPosition.Builder();
                    builder.zoom(15);
                    builder.target(target);

                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(builder.build()));

                    TraceRoute trace = new TraceRoute();
                    trace.execute(latMt + "," + logMt, t1 + "," + t2);

                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(v, "Localização não encontrada, aguarde um pouco!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Eu sempre quis saber também. Queria poder colocar uma recompensa nesta pergunta agora.

Comment: Entendo que a diferença entre as duas imagens é o _zoom_, não dá pra ter certeza sobre a precisão (a menos que aumente o _zoom_ na primeira).

Comment: Achei a pergunta interessante, mas não entendi se a dúvida é relativa ao _zoom_, à escala que o _google_ usa em cada nível de _zoom_ ou à precisão (do tipo "estou aqui e o marcador mostra do outro lado da rua")

Comment: @rLinhares cara, a primeira imagem, o raio da precisão está cerca de quase 5 km, na segunda ela não tem nem 2 m, como a diferença está no zoom? A primeiro imagem a localização mostrada é quase 10 km da minha casa

Comment: Entendi.. então pra mim a questão também é válida :P

Comment: @rLinhares A questão foi marcada como duplicada, eu olhei a outra e realmente funcionou, com getAccuracy a primeira imagem retornou 4089, aguardei pegar minha localização certa e olhei dnv, retornou 10, então eu comparei aqui quando ele for menor que 25, a precisão está praticamente correta

Comment: @WotonSampaio massa, vlw a informação